# Is it possible to make Unity Indicators with Java?

Tags: unity, java, indicator

I just started to learn Java and I wonder if there is any way to make an indicator through it. I was looking for it [here](https://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/)

But I can only find documentation there for C and Python… So is it only possible with those languages?

Comment: I've seen a couple indicators written in Java but for older, much older versions of Unity. It may have been possible in the past, but I don't know about now. Look for APIs that allow you to build Gtk apps in Java. Because indicator is basically that - a gtk menu

Comment: Its easy to display in Unitiy systray application indicator area from Java and Bash. But I don't know about pull down menu support.

Answer (score -2):

The Java language is meant to be cross-platform. It should not contain any features that cannot be implemented in all operating systems. However, there is a way to get around the system.

Java provides a built-in way to invoke functions that are written in a different language. This is the JNI (Java Native Interface). JNI allows you to call C code dynamically from your Java, and get the results of that code. You could implement the Unity Indicators in C, and dynamically call the code required to generate them from Java. Here is a good tutorial on using JNI: [JNI Intro](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html) There are also libraries that abstract the use of JNI to really simple terms. [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) is one of them.

Comment: How is a question on writing Unity indicators ot on AskUbuntu?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Because AskUbuntu is about users of Ubuntu systems, not developers for programs intended for use on Ubuntu systems. Either way, I answered the question, and am willing to delete the off-topic part.

Comment: You might have misread the section. AU *is* for developers of stuff to be used on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @JacobVlijm removed both sections